EF Core Bidirectional Many To Many duplicate key
I think I am getting lost with this topic :(
I have a problem on mapping a very common NxM relationship using EF Core 8.
Let's make it simple. These are the entity classes
public sealed class Student {
    private readonly List<Classes> _classes;

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Class> Classes { 
        get {
            return _classes;
        }
    }

    public void AddClass(Class entity) {
        _classes.Add(entity); 
    }
}

public sealed class Class {
    private readonly List<Student> _students;

    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Class> Students { 
        get {
            return _students;
        }
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student entity) {
        _students.Add(entity); 
    }
}

I am using an explicit join Entity containing only the Ids of both entities
public sealed class StudentClass {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
}

Then let's have a look at the mapping
//Student
builder
    .HasMany(x => x.Classes)
    .WithMany(x => x.Students)
    .UsingEntity<StudentClass>(
        "StudentClasses",
        l => l
            .HasOne<Class>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ClassId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(r => r.StudentId)
            .IsRequired(),
        r => r
            .HasOne<Student>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.ClassId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.StudentId)
            .IsRequired(),
        j => {
            j.HasKey(ur => new { ur.StudentId, ur.ClassId });
            j.ToTable(TableNames.StudentClassTableName);
        }
    );

//Class
builder
    .HasMany(x => x.Students)
    .WithMany(x => x.Classes)
    .UsingEntity<StudentClass>(
        "StudentClasses",
        l => l
            .HasOne<Student>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.StudentId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(r => r.ClassId)
            .IsRequired(),
        r => r
            .HasOne<Class>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.StudentId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.ClassId)
            .IsRequired(),
        j => {
            j.HasKey(ur => new { ur.StudentId, ur.ClassId });
            j.ToTable(TableNames.StudentClassTableName);
        }
    );

My aim is to implement as simple use case like Student register to Class or similarly Add student to Class by using code like the following in a controller action
public IActionResult RegisterStudentToClass(int studentId, int classId) {
    var student = _context
        .Students
        .Include(s => s.Classes)
        .SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentId == studentId); 
    var class = _context
        .Classes
        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ClassId == classId);

    student.AddClass(class);
    _context.SaveChanges();   //>>>>>> Error happens here
}

However when I try to call the AddToClass method, on SaveChanges EF Core tries to insert the Class object in the database which ends with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_StudentClass'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.StudentClass'. The duplicate key value is ...
My objective is to only add a new relationship within StudentClass. However it seems that EF Core also tries to add again previous existing relationships that were loaded with the Student instead.
Any suggestion?

You didn't post any code that loads, creates or saves those objects. Where do they come from? How are they loaded and saved? Unless they're loaded by the DbContext, EF has no way of knowing that one of them already exists and will try to INSERT them when SaveChanges is called. If the objects come from an API call and the code calls DbContext.Add, they'll be attached in the Added state and INSERTed.

Have you considered just adding a public List<Classes> Classes navigational property to your student, and a corresponding List<Students> Students property to your Class? EF should, by default, create the mapping table for you., It might be useful to test with the blog/post example from the documentation

I am not sure I got your comment as per your meaning. The code that load a student is very simple (e.g. for a student  context.Students.Include( x => x.Classes).SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentId == studentId). As per my understanding this will load a single Student with its current registered classes. These classes should have the Unchenged state internally. Am I right? From an API a new classId is then received to be registered. After loading the student as I showed, and the class to add as per the input classId, the class is added to the student object.

Please [edit] your question to add new information, including the code that throws the exception, because that's what it's all about. Also, where is this RegisterToClass method? It's not clear now if you try to save a StudentClass or use the main entities to create a relationship.

@GertArnold: thanks for the answer. You're right, I am trying to use the main entity (Student) to create a new relationship. The error also happen if I try the other way round, adding a student to a class. I edited the question to provide a better example. The edit begins from My aim is to implement after the mapping.

As suggested, you can do this much simpler by just inserting a StudentClass object. After all, you have this explicit join entity and that's what it's for. That said, the exception is pretty clear: the relationship you try to establish by student.AddClass(class); already exists in the database.

In this case I should change the mapping, right?

Not sure that EF can track and even initialise IReadOnlyCollection navigation property without setter.

You don't configure the mapping twice.  You can configure the mapping starting from Students or Classes, but it shouldn't be both.

I have tried in many ways. More than one comment is correct but I think that the biggest issue present in my setup was described by @SvyatoslavDanyliv. By following the examples available on Microsoft website I have been able to make it working with different configurations. However none of them works with IReadOnlyCollection as in my original example. If anyone write this as an answer I can confirm it as correct. Thanks everybody
